# I want to copy a link which is stored in a variable in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**The link is passes to child component via props. Ive used: `navigator.clipboard.writeText(link)`
This is not working in mobile devices!**

````
         onClick={() => {
           navigator.clipboard.writeText(link);
           alert(`${name} Link Copied to Clipboard`);
         }}
       >
         Copy Link!
       </button>```
````

Answer (score 0):

**[SOLVED]**

```
function copyToClipboard(link) {
var textField = document.createElement("textarea");
textField.innerText = link;
document.body.appendChild(textField);
textField.select();
document.execCommand("copy");
textField.remove();
```

}